# access data property vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

here is a piece of my code:

```
$(function () {

    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {

            myObject : {
                id: "",
                _class : "",
                contentType : "TEXT",
                textValue : "",
            },
            selected_language : "ENGLISH",

        }
```

I want to find a way to fill the `textValue` property with what is in `selected_language`.
which mean that my object will look like:

```
myObject : {
                id: "",
                _class : "",
                contentType : "TEXT",
                textValue : "ENGLISH",
            }
```

Thanks for your help in advance, I am quite stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can access `data` property using `this` in Vue instance,

```
this.myObject.textValue = this.selected_language
```

If you want to update the `data` automatically when app is mounted then use [`created`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) hook

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        myObject : {
                id: "",
                _class : "",
                contentType : "TEXT",
                textValue : "",
            },
            selected_language : "ENGLISH",
        },
    created: function(){
        this.myObject.textValue = this.selected_language
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Muthu. however how do I implement  this line of code whithin my own code exactly.

Comment: where exactly you want to update? update outside Vue instance?